# Adding version number to Jenkins build artifact

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been ordered to migrate a dotnet build from Bamboo to Jenkins. I used a Freestyle job to run a powershell script, using the PowerShell plugin and successfully built it. However I need to add version number to the built artifact. The Bamboo job uses:
`~\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe package -pl $fullDir -f "netcoreapp3.1" -o Payment.${bamboo.majorVersion}.${bamboo.minorVersion}.${bamboo.revisionVersion}.${bamboo.buildNumber}.zip`

I went into Jenkins Configuration and in Global Properties, created Environment variables named - buildNumber, majorVersion, minorVersion and revisionVersion, giving it values and in the Build part of the Freestyle job, I used:
`~\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe package -pl $fullDir -f "netcoreapp3.1" -o Payment.${env.majorVersion}.${env.minorVersion}.${env.revisionVersion}.${env.buildNumber}.zip`

However the name of the built artifact is: Payment.....zip

1. How can I pass the variable values?
2. Is there a way to auto increment the revisionNumber and buildNumber, instead of hard coding it?

I'm very new to both Bamboo and Jenkins. Any help would be extremely helpful.

Regards
Ramesh

Comment: Where did you set those, Globally or at Job level?? Do you have [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) installed? You might also want [Build With Parameters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/), depending on what incrementa.

Comment: @Ian W
 I set them at: Manage Jenkins > Configure System> Global Properties > Environment Variables
I did not have Environment Injector. Have installed that now. Can't figure out how to use that to inject the variables saved in Environment Variables.

I tried Build With Parameters and changed the build step to:
~\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe package -pl $fullDir -f "netcoreapp3.1" -o Payment.${params.majorVersion}.${params.minorVersion}.${params.revisionVersion}.${params.buildNumber}.zip
However ended up with Payment.....zip again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd not configure this things globally as they seem job specific. Nevertheless,

Install the [Environment Injector plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/). You now have two options:
**General** tab
[ X ] Prepare an environment for the run

**Build Environment** tab
[ X ] Inject environment variables to the build process

Set the "**Properties Content**" (that's an environment variable).

[image: Job Config -Build Env]

In your shell step( no need to preface with ${env....} ):

Execute Shell step:

```
#!sh -
echo ${FOO}.${BUILD_NUMBER}
echo ${LABEL}
```

Output:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building in workspace C:\Users\jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Foo
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
FOO=bar

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[Foo] $ sh - C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins281351632631450693.sh
bar.8
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You'll also see at the bottom of the Execute Shell step a link to `${JENKINS_URL}/env-vars.html` which lists variables available to shell scripts, which includes `BUILD_NUMBER`; use that in lieu of `buildNumber`.

The plugin also supports configuration same at both the [Global and the Node level](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/#plugin-content-at-node-master-and-agent-level).
You can also have individual build steps to inject / change variables between job steps (we use this to set specific JAVA_HOME for SonarQube step).

You will also see an [Environment variables] button on the LH side of each build log to inspect what you ran with (see below).

---

If you add [Build With Parameters plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/) then you can be prompted to supply values for variables when triggering the job which can be consumed in the same fashion without re-configuring the job (it won't remember them, but you will see a [Parameters] button on the LH side of each build log to inspect what you ran with.

[image: Job buttons]

---

The [Version Number plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/versionnumber/) can provides greater flexibility, say you want to AutoIncrement and the "`BUILD_NUMBER`" option is too limiting, it offers a variable `BUILDS_ALL_TIME`, which can use the above defined variables or hard-coded constants to aggregate a version label and optionally control which it is incremented (eg: only increment on successful builds). eg:

[ X ] Prepare an environment for the run
Properties Content
`FOO=bar`

[ X ] Create a formatted version number
Environment Variable Name [ `BUILD-${FOO}.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}` ]
Skip Builds worse than [ SUCCESS ]

Execute Shell step:

```
#!sh -
echo ${FOO}.${BUILD_NUMBER}
echo ${LABEL}
```

Output:

```
[Foo] $ sh - C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins4160554383847615506.sh
bar.10
BUILD-bar.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ian. That was extremely helpful. I used the Version Number plugin and the BUILDS_ALL_TIME option.